# Freeing a struct within a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc, calloc

So, I'm working in C and I'm allocating an array of type struct, and within that struct I'm also allocating another array of different struct.

```
typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_NAME + 1];
    ITEM *items;
} database;

typedef struct {
    char name[NAME_MAX + 1];
}ITEM;
```

```
database *array = (database*)malloc(n1 * sizeof(database));

array[i].items = (ITEM*)calloc(n2 * sizeof*(ITEM));
```

Does the command `free(array);` take care of freeing the whole thing, including the ITEM array I allocated within it?

Comment: No, you must match each call to the malloc family of functions to one free call.

Comment: C does not do any magic for you. You need to make sure that every allocation is matched with deallocation. You should use a memory debugger like e.g. valgrind to check.

Comment: Also: don't typecast the `malloc` and `calloc` return values. This is not necessary and will more likely introduce nasty bugs than do anything good for you.

Comment: So I basically just have to make a cycle to free every item  `free(array[i].items)` and only then free the `free(array[i])`?

Comment: yes. `free()` in a loop the *sub-arrays* first. `for (i...) { free(array[i].items); } free(array);`

Comment: For the code shown to compile, you must reverse the order of the two typedefs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's what I have written in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to free every single data allocation done by `calloc()` or `malloc()`.

###### A few points

- `calloc(n2 * sizeof*(ITEM));` is completely wrong. You need write like this

```c
array[i].items = calloc(n2, sizeof(ITEM));
```

- You don't need to typecast the value returned from `malloc()` and `calloc()`
- Always check whether heap-allocation was successful or not, by checking the pointer against `NULL`
- struct `ITEM` should be declared before struct `database`, to avoid forward-declaration error
- You need to free the resources using a loop which will iterate till `n1`

```c
for (size_t i = 0; i < n1; i++)
{
    free(array[i].items);
}
free(array);
```